# How to put a google map on JQUERY Mobile?

Tags: javascript, php, css, google-maps, jquery-mobile

When tried to run the code , The map doesn't show up, and it shows up this error`"Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys "`. What are the possible solution for this? 
This is the script that I have added:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

These are the codes that I have put at the js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 11,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(1.363083, 103.909836),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                        myOptions);

                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.443107  , 103.795681);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: "Map "
                })
            });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys` is a warning, not an error.  It won't prevent the map from appearing (API keys are not currently required to display a map).  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: trigger the `resize`-event of the map on [`pagecontainerchange`](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-change)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error suggests that you haven't included an API key with your Google Maps api call. You need to go to https://developers.google.com/maps/, sign up for an API key, and include it in your call. Below is a really simple example using the JS api.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY></script>
```